# Auto-increment cells for named rows and named columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, named-ranges

I am looking for a way to reference cells inside named range and have it be understandable for person looking through the spreadsheet.

I have this spreadsheet:

```
  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
1     jan feb mar apr may sum sum2
2 car 1   2   3   4   5   
3 bot 3   4   5   6   7
4 top 10  20  30  40  50
```

So "car" is the named range B2:F2
and "jan is the named range for B2:B4

In ideal world I see myself doing this:

```
G2 = car jan
```

Then when I copy-paste the above formula to H2, Excel auto-increments "jan" to "feb" and I get

```
G3 = car feb
```

This is obviously not working. I saw different ways people suggest getting such results, but it leaves me with some long lookup formulas, while I want the person reading the spreadsheet be able to intuitively understand all the references without knowing what formulas stand for.

If this is absolutely not possible, I would be happy to at least be able to refer to cells by name of the row and letter of the column. So that I can do:

```
G2 = SOMEFORMULA(car, C)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the ranges named as you say write in G2 the next draggable formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$4,ROW(INDIRECT($A2)),COLUMN(INDIRECT(B$1)))
```

And of course you would be able to write something like

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$4,ROW(car),COLUMN(feb))
```

but that formula wouldn't be draggable.

(Note $A$1:$F$4 is your dataset reference)

Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA solution. Using macros for something that can be done with worksheet formulas isn't the best practice, However, it gives you the functionality you want. Create a module in your workbook and add this code to the module. Don't forget to save your file as .xlsm

```
Function SOMEFORMULA(item As Variant, month As Variant)

Dim rng As Range

'set your lookup range
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F4")

SOMEFORMULA = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rng, WorksheetFunction.Match(item, WorksheetFunction.Index(rng, 0, 1), 0), WorksheetFunction.Match(month, WorksheetFunction.Index(rng, 1, 0), 0))

End Function
```

My recommendation is to use a named range for your data array, such that this line:

```
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F4")
```

Becomes:

```
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("named_range")
```

And can be edited from the workbook.

You might also want to change the formulate name from "SOMEFORMULA()" to something smaller/ more appropriate.

The results are as follows:

[image]

Comment: I just tried it, but when I copy =SOMEFORMULA("car","feb") to next cell, sum2 for example - I still get =SOMEFORMULA("car","feb") and not =SOMEFORMULA("car","mar"). So it will not auto-increment to next column's name?

Comment: No, but you could use cell references, like `=SOMEFORMULA($A2,C$1)` to replace `=SOMEFORMULA("car","mar")` at which point you could drag it along or down. You will find that if you want to be able to drag the formula you always need cell references, at which point you lose the readability that you wanted.